# Drawing on a canvas using a holder and a separate thread does not show anything on the screen

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, surfaceview

I wanted to use a SurfaceView with a "sticky" canvas. i.e. one that preserves its state and does not get ivalidated. I followed an example that showed how to set up a holder and use a separate thread for the drawing. The idea is that when touching anywhere on the SurfaceView, `drawStuff` will be called, given some paint, and a random rectangle should be drawn.

Although the code executes perfectly, nothing is drawn at the end.

```
public class DrawingView extends SurfaceView implements Callback {

    Paint currentPaint;
    float verts[];
    private Boolean drawing = false;

    class DrawingThread extends Thread {
        private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
        private SurfaceView surfaceView;
        private Boolean isRunning = false;

        public void setIsRunning(Boolean isRunning) {
            this.isRunning = isRunning;
        }

        public DrawingThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, SurfaceView surfaceView) {
            super();
            this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
            this.surfaceView = surfaceView;
        }


        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(isRunning) {
                Canvas c = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                surfaceView.draw(c);
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }
    }

    DrawingThread thread;


    public DrawingView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setWillNotDraw(false);
        this.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        this.getHolder().addCallback(this);
        this.thread = new DrawingThread(getHolder(), this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        if (drawing) {
            // TEST CODE. WILL NEVER USE THIS IN PRODUCTION
            canvas.drawRect(new Rect(new Float(Math.random()*200).intValue(), 20, new Float(Math.random()*200).intValue(), 30), currentPaint);
            drawing = false;
        }

    }


    public void drawStuff(Paint paint) {
        currentPaint = paint;

        drawing = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        thread.setIsRunning(true);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        thread.setIsRunning(false);

    }


}
```

and the paint set up:

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        paint.setAlpha(55);

        ((DrawingView) v).drawStuff(paint);

        //v.invalidate();

        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, you're not actually drawing things when you think you are.  Calling `draw()` schedules the draw on your UI thread, but doesn't actually call `onDraw` from your background thread so your `Canvas` is no longer valid with respect to the surface.  You should render whatever you are doing into a `Bitmap` object and when you are ready to write to the surface, notify the UI thread.  The UI thread can then lock the surface, draw the bitmap into the `Canvas`, then unlock and post the `Canvas` to the surface.